# Support Ticketing system

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your favorite ticketing system?](https://serverfault.com/questions/43072/whats-your-favorite-ticketing-system)

Could anyone recommend a good Support ticketing software?
Preferably open source and easy to manage and backup.

If one would recommend a commercial one, please do ?

Comment: What are your OS requirements? What type of hardware do you have available?

Comment: original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534185/support-ticketing-system

Comment: +1 was just about to ask the same question myself!

Answer (score 6):

[RT](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) is nice.

Comment: We've just deployed RT, and it's proving to be a good solution. Not the easiest or quickest to get up and running in a satisfactory way, but nothing too bad.  Takes a bit to wrap your head around the way it works - Scrips etc - but if you invest the time it'll pay off.

Answer (score 4):

We use [SpiceWorks](http://www.spiceworks.com/).  Not open source, but it is free as in beer.

Comment: +1 for SpiceWorks .. although it is ad-supported.

Comment: I agree with Joel too, Spiceworks is one good system. Has flexible reporting, Inventory, Good Customizations and easy to implement.

Comment: I wish we could use Spiceworks, it's very easy to use for YOU. The reporting isn't very robust, but I love the reply e-mail commands: #add 30min #assign me #close

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked at [least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941405/what-is-the-best-open-source-help-ticket-system) [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114007/free-supportticket-software) on StackOverflow, and there is lots of good info in the answers.

A couple of alternatives that I haven't seen mentioned here or there ...

I have heard good things about [AxoSoft OnTime](http://www.axosoft.com/ontime), although I have never used it.  While it is oriented to software development teams, the help desk and project management features are (apparently) flexible enough to work for general IT management.  The cost seems reasonable.

Also, the [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) "issue tracking" system is also development centric, but their wiki has [information](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+as+a+Support+System) about setting it up as a general IT help desk support system.  If you do development, the ability to see **all** of the IT work in one place is priceless.  I tried to setup FogBugz for that and did not get good results.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your requirements, this would be my best suffestion, free and open source:

**dotProject**

PHP web-based project management framework that includes modules for companies, projects, tasks (with Gantt charts), forums, files, calendar, contacts, tickets/helpdesk, multi-language support, user/module permissions and themes

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotproject/

Here is another one of our clients love:

**Slick-Ticket is a no-nonsense trouble ticketing/help desk solution.**

This is a simple, to-the-point system. It was born out of loathing of the system that I was forced to use. It was tested in a live environment with hundreds of users and ultimately de-throned our expensive and bloated ticketing software.

Full Integrated with Active Directory means not another layer of permissions to add 
Intuitive interface allows users to jump right in

Integrated help/faq system for administrators to inform users

**Details**
Utilizes .Net 3.5 (C#)

Asp.Net architecture built with Linq-to-SQL

Utilizes Asp.Net AJAX and the AJAX Control Toolkit

Completely customizable colors/themes

Installation program included, just load it on your machine and follow the directions

Localized - Available Languages

Website: http://slick-ticket.com

http://slickticket.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [eSupport](http://www.kayako.com/solutions/esupport/). I our company we have good experience with this commercial product. With a lot of ajax support. Gives a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends what you want to use it for.

When I was working in a company supporting users, we used spiceworks, which is a great free application and provides you with a lot of tools to view a snapshot of your network.

Now, I'm providing support to clients externally, so we have recently migrated to [Zendesk](http://zendesk.com) and we think it's brilliant, it's simple, easy, it's growing and improving constantly and the best part is that it's cheap!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend a commercial one called [FocalScope](http://www.focalscope.com). It comes with a lot of features and a great interface to help you speed up your customer support and enhance your business’ inner communication. Our customers contact a support department and internally we route it to available agents automatically, using the ticket queue and based on the type of query. There also has an archiving routine built in and management is easy since it is installed on one server or in the cloud.